# How can a ranged rogue sneak attack?

Tags: ranged-attack, sneak-attack, pathfinder-2e, flat-footed

A player of mine started to play a rogue in pathfinder 2e, he was already playing a rogue in DnD 5e. He feels a bit frustrated that it was impossible to profit from the flanking rule to sneak attack.

My question is how the rogue can sneak attack with a ranged weapon?

I know that he can use the hide action and then attack but what are the other opportunities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do have a few options in the early game. (I will avoid discussing options at level 10 or higher)

First, all Rogues have the **Surprise Attack** ability, which makes their foes flat-footed for the first round of combat (though you do need to beat their initiative).

Assuming you have *some* melee combatants in your party, consider strategizing with them to impose the **grabbed** condition -- in addition to immobilization, it also leaves whomever is grabbed flat-footed.

Likewise, a **prone** combatant is considered flat-footed -- and unlike 5e, prone enemies are not inherently harder to hit from range (though they can take-cover to net +2 AC, they're still flat-footed and still have to spend the action to do so).

At level 8, you get a strong feat option to guarantee *some* sneak attack bonus damage through [Slystriker](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=577), though that obviously requires an open feat. [Unbalancing Blow](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=559) is another option that makes opponents flat-footed after you score a critical hit.

[Dread Striker](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=561) rounds out the feat options, making enemies flat-footed when they are Frightened. (Works well with Intimidate->Demoralize, and your party members can help out too)

Finally, there are a couple of ways to throw money at the problem -- if you have an alchemist party member (or someone else who doesn't mind lobbing bombs), [Bottled Lightning](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=76) inflicts flat-footed on a hit. Perhaps a more "rogue-ly" solution involves poison - [Giant Centipede](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=113) and [Hunting Spider](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=118) venoms can both apply Flat-Footed if your target fails their saving throws. (Make sure to pre-apply so that you don't spend extra actions on your first turn!)